# Convert var into List<MapPdf>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a program that I used a variable of type **List < MapPdf >** that I will detach in variables when filling I would like to have the possibility to use it another time but I did not have the right to identify it again as

```
    public static void Create(List<MapPdf> pps, Saison s, Agence agence)
    {
        foreach (var pelerins in grouped)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pelerins.Key) || pelerins.Count() <= 0)
                break;
            if (writer.PageEvent == null)
            {
                writer.PageEvent = new Header_List()
                {
                    travel = ctx.Travels.Include("Transport").First(v => v.UniqueId == pelerins.Key),
                    travelretour = ctx.Travels.Find(pelerins.First().UniqueIdRetour),
                    Agence = agence,
                    CountAllPelerin = pelerins.Count().ToString(),
                    CountFeminin = pelerins.Count(x => x.Sexe == PelerinSexe.Feminin).ToString(),
                    CountMasculin = pelerins.Count(x => x.Sexe == PelerinSexe.Masculin).ToString(),
                    NomGroupe = pelerins.First().Groupe,
                    NumeroDoc = writer.PageNumber
                };


            }
        }
    }
```

And i want to use pelerins as a List when i used in another function when it is of this declaration

I used **List < MapPdf > pls = pelerins.ToList();** but it does not work

```
         CreateFr(pls, false, cb,  s);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to `var pelerins` within the for-each loop and if I understand the problem, you are unable use it into another method , because `var pelerins` is a local variable encapsulated within the for-each loop -It does not exist outside it.

You could do the following:

```
//public property to retrieve pelerins
public List <MapPdf> pls new List<MapPdf>();
 ...
 ...
public static void Create(List<MapPdf> pps, Saison s, Agence agence)
{    
 foreach (var pelerins in grouped)
 {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pelerins.Key) || pelerins.Count() <= 0)
            break;
        if (writer.PageEvent == null)
        {
           //do logic
           ...
           //store the one you are interested in, so you can use it later on
           pls = pelerins.ToList(); 
        }


 }
}
```